# jquery Find TD of TR with Class and make changes (for a Telerik MVC grid)

Tags: jquery, telerik-mvc

this is my mark up

```
<tr class="t-detail-row">
    <td class="t-hierarchy-cell"></td>           
    <td class="t-detail-cell" colspan="5"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to find the tr with class **t-detail-row** and remove the child td with class **t-hierarchy-cell** and change the colspan of td with class **t-detail-cell**

I tried something like this

```
var newcolspan = $(e.row).find('.t-detail-row').children('td.t-detail-cell').attr('colspan');

$(e.row).find('.t-detail-row').children('td.t-hierarchy-cell').remove()
.children('td.t-detail-cell').attr('colspan',newcolspan+1);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

**More Specific Details about the situation**

---

Hi, How can i call client jquery Function when grid expand is fired.

all that i want to achieve is.
when we expand the Telerik MVC grid 
we get this mark up in detail row

```
<tr class="t-detail-row">
<td class="t-hierarchy-cell"></td>
<td class="t-detail-cell" colspan="5"></td>
</tr>
```

i want to eliminate  `<td class="t-hierarchy-cell"></td>` in it.

and get the mark up as

```
<tr class="t-detail-row">
<td class="t-detail-cell" colspan="Current+1"></td>
</tr>
```

for this i though of doing some thing like this

on  grid expand event, if i can call a jquery function
then because i wont have the detail-row markup generated until we expand the grid

```
function onExpandingtheGrid(){
$('tr.t-detail-row').find('td.t-hierarchy-cell').remove();
$('tr.t-detail-row').find('td.t-detail-cell').attr('colspan',newcolspan+1);
}
```

Thanks

**Solution**

---

just add this line in your telerik code

```
.ClientEvents(exp => exp.OnDetailViewExpand("onExpandingtheGrid"))
```

and rest as mentioned in your above jquery function yahoo!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

with separate functions its:

```
$('tr.t-detail-row').find('td.t-hierarchy-cell').remove();
$('tr.t-detail-row').find('td.t-detail-cell').attr('colspan',newcolspan+1);
```

i used find in this case because it looks like you are trying to use a target row for a click or something. replace the tr selector with your target if that is the case.

Comment: I have updated my requirement more specifically, please look in it. And that you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('tr.t-detail-row td.t-hierarchy-cell').remove();
$('tr.t-detail-row td.t-detail-cell').attr('colspan', X); // replace X with desired colspan value
```

Comment: I have updated my requirement more specifically, please look in it. And that you very much for your time.